# bat to create text files with variables extracted from a list

Tags: variables, batch-file, extract

I need a bat file that can create some text files with some variables.

Path of file with variables (warning have spaces in path)

```
D:\Programmi Installati\Macro\variables.txt
```

Content of variables.txt

```
csvLine = 1 ; csvLine <= 100 ; csvLine++
csvLine = 101 ; csvLine <= 200 ; csvLine++
csvLine = 201 ; csvLine <= 300 ; csvLine++
csvLine = 301 ; csvLine <= 400 ; csvLine++
csvLine = 401 ; csvLine <= 500 ; csvLine++
csvLine = 501 ; csvLine <= 600 ; csvLine++
```

First file to create

```
for (csvLine = 1 ; csvLine <= 100 ; csvLine++) (ROW 1 VARIABLES.TXT)

{
   iimDisplay("Loading Csv Row Number: "+csvLine)
   iimSet ("-var_CSVLINE", csvLine);
   iimPlay("macro.iim");
   iimDisplay("")
   window.stop();
}

/// Close Browser ///
window.close();
window.close();
window.close();
```

Second file to create:

```
for (csvLine = 101 ; csvLine <= 200 ; csvLine++) (ROW 2 VARIABLES.TXT)

{
   iimDisplay("Loading Csv Row Number: "+csvLine)
   iimSet ("-var_CSVLINE", csvLine);
   iimPlay("macro.iim");
   iimDisplay("")
   window.stop();
}

/// Close Browser ///
window.close();
window.close();
window.close();
```

I prefer to save this file with this sintax

```
filename-1.js (file that includes variable in 1 row)
filename-2.js (file that includes variable in 2 row)
filename-3.js (file that includes variable in 3 row)
```

In the content of file need to create a file with fix part and variable extracted from variables.txt.

Adding the complete path with spaces of folder to save all files created in a prefered folder.

Thanks

Comment: "I need a bat file...". What keeps you from writing one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need are `for` loop and redirection.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set line=0
cd /d D:\Programmi Installati\Macro

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (variables.txt) do (
    set /a line+=1
    (
        echo for (%%a^)
        echo.
        echo {
        echo    iimDisplay("Loading Csv Row Number: "+csvLine^)
        echo    iimSet ("-var_CSVLINE", csvLine^);
        echo    iimPlay("macro.iim"^);
        echo    iimDisplay(""^)
        echo    window.stop(^);
        echo }
        echo.
        echo /// Close Browser ///
        echo window.close(^);
        echo window.close(^);
        echo window.close(^);
    )>filename-!line!.js
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the script, the path where the files created will be saved as you specify ? Example path "D:\Programmi Installati\Macro\Saved" can you add in the script the parth where the files will be saved?

Comment: `cd /d PATH` will be your current path, where all your access/saved/created files will be. If you want to save to other folder, change it to `cd /d D:\Programmi Installati`. And in the `for` loop, replace the path to `Macro\variables.txt`. Lastly, replace the file name to `Saved\filename-!line!.js`.